# "Select text, Drag something" is broken on Trackpad on Mac OS Monterey 12.5

Tags: trackpad, click

Not quite sure what happened but I am no longer able to "hard click" my trackpad, for example to login (click your logo) or select text, "hold and drag". To that end I have to resort to using old school mouse.

Could it be a physical problem? I can't think of anyone in my house plating with settings to turn this off

Please help